# Setting email field read only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using Woocommerce I've removed the shipping addresses/details from the checkout as they are not required but for logged in users I still want to show the email field but show it so it's not editable:

```
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // change billing_email to read only
 } else {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);
 }
```

how is it I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each field can have [custom attributes](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/441530f54edaf70582e8f3e24ff4d0a3c86d2da5/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1669), stored as an array:

```
$fields['billing']['billing_email']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'readonly' => 'readonly' );
```